Learning Python: I have an IndexError and I don't understand why
I'm programming a Poker game to learn Python. For my card draw I take 5 random cards out of the starting_deck list to put them in a card_on_board list and sometimes i get an IndexError.
Here is how:
def card_draw():

    while len(card_on_board) < 5:

        draw = random.randint(0, len(Deck.starting_deck))

        card_on_board.append(Deck.starting_deck[draw])

        del Deck.starting_deck[draw]

Most of the time it works perfectly, but sometimes I get an IndexError:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    CardDraw.card_draw()
  File "C:\Users\*\CardDraw.py", line 13, in card_draw
    card_on_board.append(Deck.starting_deck[draw])
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

It's a pretty simple code, I don't understand why sometimes the index between 0 and starting_deck length is not a correct index. Can someone help me ? Thanks a lot !

Hint: Python arrays are zero-based; so the last index is one less than the result returned by len

You could easily debug this yourself by examining the value of the variable when you get the error. What values cause it to fail? All of them? Or a particular one?

randint is a funny function that includes the upper bound in its range. Use randrange instead. https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint

Thanks a lot tripleee and James K. Polk ! random.randint(0, (len(Deck.starting_deck)-1)) seems to be perfect ! or random.randrange(0, len(Deck.starting_deck)) too ! I understand why thanks !
